# Error converting Image from Base64 - HTMLImageElement is broken

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm attempting to load an image and convert it to binary data through PHP, then decode the data and load it onto an HTML5 canvas through Javascript. However I'm running into the following error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
```

Here's all of my code, the only bit of PHP is up front. Please note I also tried just using the btoa method. I found the hexToBase64 method on stackoverflow when trying to find an fix to my problem.

```
<?php
    $image_data = file_get_contents('test.png');
    $encoded_image = base64_encode($image_data);
    $btoa = "hexToBase64('" . $encoded_image . "')";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Experimental Reader</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="reader" width="100%" height="100%">Whoah, your browser is old! You need to update it to use our reader.</canvas>
    </body>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var canvas  = document.getElementById("reader");
            var ctx     = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var image   = document.createElement('img');
            image.src='data:image/png;base64,' + <?php echo $btoa; ?>;
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        function hexToBase64(str) {
            return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to make sure the image is loaded. dataURLs are fast, not instant. get it to work in a hard-coded yet hidden <img> tag first, then move on to making it dynamic.

Comment: @dandavis, Even working with the `image.onload` method, this does not fix the issue. How am I supposed to do this with a hidden <img> tag if the image is supposed to be rendered on the HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I am loading the dataURL from javascript, and I have 2 problems: 1 - `onload()` doesn't get fired, 2 - When I force it (after 2 secs of timeout) it tells me that the image is broken :(

Comment: @TIMINeutron - The problem in my case was that the image was not yet loaded. Load the dataURL and use a callback. I don't have the code anymore to display, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
    $image_data = file_get_contents('test.png');
    $encoded_image = base64_encode($image_data);
    $btoa = "hexToBase64('" . $encoded_image . "')";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Experimental Reader</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="reader" width="100%" height="100%">Whoah, your browser is old! You need to update it to use our reader.</canvas>
    </body>

    <script>
        var canvas;

        window.onload = function() {
            canvas       = document.getElementById("reader");
            var image    = document.createElement('img');
            image.onload = imageLoaded;
            image.src='data:image/png;base64,' + <?php echo $btoa; ?>;
        }

        function hexToBase64(str) {
            return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
        }

        function imageLoaded(evnt) {
            //after successful image loading we can draw it
            var ctx     = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(evnt.target, 0, 0);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```